# How can I debug evaled JavaScript within AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, eval, source-maps

I have some arbitrary javascript code that is run via the following method:

1. download it onto client browser via ajax call
2. pass resulting code string into javascript `eval` function.

**Note: I cannot download/run the code by adding its file URL to a** `<script>`**'s** `src` **property because the code must run within a particular scope.**

I would like to debug this code in Google Chrome. I am able to do this using plain Javascript, but not when I am using AngularJS. How can I fix this?

Example 1 (plain JS, I am given option to inspect `code.js`):

```
var codeToRun = ""
+"var a = 1;\n"
+"var b = 2;\n"
+"This line will fail\n"
+"//@ sourceURL=code.js";

eval(codeToRun);
```

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSwdp.png
demo: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexLeung/mpjrwmbm/

Example 2 (AngularJS, I am not given option to inspect `code.js`):

```
var codeToRun = ""
+"var a = 1;\n"
+"var b = 2;\n"
+"This line will fail\n"
+"//@ sourceURL=code.js";

angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    eval(codeToRun);
});
```

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff95J.png
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oeoaep0o/

Comment: maybe try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval

Comment: I mean, honestly, if I were you I'd change the design.  Why does it need to run in that particular scope?  Make it so that's not the case.

Comment: You could just have a global function that you call in your controller, and pass in whatever you need from the scope as an argument.

Comment: The downloaded JS contains a complex array (the array contains functions and objects, etc.), and I need to set this array equal to a variable within the current scope, because this complex array is meant to be private (not available to other parts of the code outside the scope).

Comment: There is no reason you can't do this by passing in the variable from the current scope.

Comment: As to your suggestion (your second comment), I tried that, but still was unable to inspect the evaled code.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my suggestion, then.  Include the other file as a regular script, except instead of having code that needs to run in the scope, modify it so that it is a global function into which you pass whatever you need when you call it.  Then call it in the controller.

Comment: Then it will no longer be private. It should not be global.

Comment: Like, I know it's annoying to have people not answer the question you asked, but if your question starts with "I am downloading a script file through ajax and evaling it so that it can access variables in a particular context" then it's time to stop and rethink your design.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's private?

Comment: Yo should make that a service

Answer (score 0):

Use a named function rather than an anonymous function. For example:

```js
var codeToRun = "var a = 1; console.log(a) //@ sourceURL=foo.js";

function evaler() 
  {
  eval(codeToRun);
  }

angular.module("foo", []).run(evaler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo"></div>
```

**References**

- [Named versus Anonymous Functions: Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#named-vs-anonymous-functions)
- [sourceURL and displayName in action: Eval and anonymous functions](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/#toc-sourceurl)